# Non-existent property tools in Page

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, tools, sdk

I have a code which used to work but after I upgraded to (K)ubuntu 16.04 and the latest Ubuntu-sdk, it doesn't work anymore. I get error **Cannot assign to non-existent property "tools"**. This is my code

```
Tab {
    page: Page {
        id: myPage
        tools: myToolbar {}

        MyTabContent {
            id: myTabContent
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

According to actual documentation it seems to be correct: https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04.4/Ubuntu.Components.ToolbarButton/

Answer (score 0):

I think it caused by this bug: [Cannot assign to non-existent property "tools"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1576463)

The fix has landed in ubuntu-ui-toolkit - 1.3.1984+16.10.20160527.2, it's available for 16.10

Apart from this, I found it works on my 16.04 system by changing the import form:

```
 import Ubuntu.Components 1.3
```

To

```
 import Ubuntu.Components 1.2
```